# How do I find ‘foo’ on an external USB drive?

Tags: macos, grep, sudo, usb-storage

Somewhere on my USB drive is a lost file with the string “foo” in it. I want to recover this using terminal on my MacBook Pro. Using `sudo` as super user I am able to list expected directories with a few batch files, e.g.

```
MyMacBook-Pro-2:~ gs$ sudo -s ls -l /volumes/Seagate*
Password: xxxxx

total 2144
-rw-r--r--@  1 gs        wheel      20484 12 Oct 10:55 .DS_Store
d--x--x--x   6 root      wheel        272 12 Oct 10:40 .DocumentRevisions-V100
drwx------   4 _unknown  _unknown     170 20 Feb  2014 .Spotlight-V100
d-wx--x--t@  3 root      wheel        102 29 Aug  2014 .TemporaryItems
d-wx-wx-wt@  3 root      wheel        102 22 Aug 17:35 .Trashes
-rw-r--r--@  1 root      wheel     938428 28 Aug  2013 .VolumeIcon.icns
-rw-r--r--@  1 _unknown  _unknown       0 24 Nov  2015 .com.apple.timemachine.donotpresent
-rw-r--r--   1 root      wheel       1493 12 Oct 13:16 .disk_label
-rw-r--r--   1 root      wheel       5981 12 Oct 13:16 .disk_label_2x
drwx------   2 _unknown  _unknown    2686 12 Oct 13:15 .fseventsd
drwxrwxrwx   4 gs        wheel        170 20 Feb  2014 2013 10
drwxrwxrwx  13 gs        wheel        612 23 Aug  2014 2014 02
drwxr-xr-x   4 gs        wheel        170 28 May 08:34 2014 06
drwxr-xr-x  16 gs        wheel        612 22 Aug 17:35 2014 08
drwxr-xr-x@  7 root      wheel        238  7 Jul  2018 Backups.backupdb
drwxr-xr-x   6 gs        wheel        374 13 Jun 08:15 DT 2019
drwxr-xr-x   5 _unknown  _unknown     306 28 May 08:29 Items Mac 2009
drwx------@  2 _unknown  _unknown     136 30 Jul  2016 Lame_Library_v3
-rwxr-xr-x@  1 root      wheel     115716 30 Sep  2013 tmbootpicker.efi
```

But when I try using `grep` to identify any file with the string *foo*, terminal complains then goes catatonic, e.g.

```
MyMacBook-Pro:~ gs$ sudo -s grep -R “foo” /volumes/Seagate*
grep: /volumes/Seagate Backup Plus Drive/.Spotlight-V100: Operation not permitted
```

It’s worth noting I recently upgraded to macOS Catalina 10.15. [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/1041749/1100567) might be relevant but [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/773974/1100567) also makes me cautious.

So before I go down a rabbit hole or do something really stupid could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The string "foo" in the file name (which the accepted answer suggests) or the file content (hinted by the use of grep)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Run `locate foo` from the Terminal

The [`locate`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/locate) command was designed for situations like this. It’s commonly used in Linux as well as macOS. Just type this from the command line:

```
locate foo
```

It will then return a list of files and full file paths with the word “foo” in it. You can also combine it with `grep` to narrow things down if you know the path you are looking for. So in your example do something like this:

```
locate foo | grep Seagate
```

If you can’t seem to find it, just force update the [`locate`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) database and try those commands again:

```
sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb
```

And if you run any of those commands and get this message:

```
WARNING: The locate database (/var/db/locate.database) does not exist. To create the database, run the following command:
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locate.plist
```

Don’t worry! Just run the command and let the locate database be built.

That message only comes up in first-run cases with `locate` and I am pretty sure that `sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locate.plist` is just the equivalent of `sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb` anyway. Might take a while to build the initial locate database, but once it’s finished it’s a great tool to use for cases like this.

Comment: When I run 'locate foo' I get 
'WARNING: The locate database (/var/db/locate.database) does not exist.
To create the database, run the following command:
  sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locate.plist'
Should I proceed ?

Comment: @Greg Yes! I have had mine set for so long that I forgot about that message. Heck, try my command of `sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb`. It should work the same and not cause damage to the system. I am on Catalina as well for reassurance.

Comment: I tried your step 3 and repeated step 1, and there it was. Fantastic!